# React Bootstrap showing Select of same size even if other size is mentioned. Seems ReactBootstrap style is not being picked

Tags: react-bootstrap

The following code gets data from server and shows the values received as `select`. The same value should be shown in 3 styles: small, default and large. However, it seems that the application is not picking any style from React Bootstrap. What am I doing wrong?

```javascript
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';


import './App.css';

function App() {

const [data, setData] = useState({}); //initial value is an empty object

useEffect(() => { 
  fetch("/home") //move to separate funcion in separate file to make it easy to test and reuse?
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(`got response: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
      return res.json();  //return json from res
    })
    .then((data) => { //data is the json returned previously. Promise chaining
      console.log(`data : ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);        
      setData(data) //override previous value of data object with value of received json object. 
    });
}, []);

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <Form.Select id="resultfromserver" size="lg" aria-label="Large select example">
          {!data ? "No data received" : Object.keys(data).map(key => (
            <option key={key} value={key}>{data[key]}</option>)) 
          }
        </Form.Select>
        <br />
        <Form.Select id="resultfromserver"  aria-label="Default select example">
          {!data ? "No data received" : Object.keys(data).map(key => (
            <option key={key} value={key}>{data[key]}</option>)) 
          }
        </Form.Select>
        <br />
        <Form.Select id="resultfromserver" size="sm" aria-label="Small select example">
          {!data ? "No data received" : Object.keys(data).map(key => (
            <option key={key} value={key}>{data[key]}</option>)) 
          }
        </Form.Select>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: You lack all the [basic form structure](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/forms/form-control), I'd guess that's a problem. (Note also this isn't a [mre] and IDs should be unique.)

Comment: thanks. i thought I could just copy/paste the example code. The code (as-is) doesn't work  even if I give different ids. I'l read more